# drRacket: regarding lists

Tags: scheme, racket

so i have 3 lists.

```
(define list1 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 15 16 17 18 19 20))
(define list2 '(2 5 6 8 10))
(define list3 '(1 4 8 9 13 15 18 19 20 25 27 29 ))
```

So begically, the list 1 is a list which contains 1 to 20.

What i want to do is, if i want to 
    list1 - list2 = '(1 3 4 6 7 9 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20)

or,
    list1 - list3 = (2 3 5 6 10 11 12 14 16 17)

I tried with length of the list but did not work but i want to keep all the list1 values except duplicated values with list3.

also, i want to do
list1 - list2 then, store the result from list1-list2 on list1, then do another subtraction like,

1. list1 - list2
2. store the result of # 1 in list1.
3. list1 - list3

can anyone give me some solution for this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can we get rid of your step 2, "store the result of #1 in list 1"? That sort of mutation just gives me the hives.

I think you're just trying to remove the elements from both lists 2 and 3 from list 1. You might do it like this:

```
(remove* (append list2 list3) list1)
```

yields....

```
'(3 7 11 12 14 16 17)
```

Comment: It's a good answer, however asking a user to change the way he tries to explain his ideas without giving him a hint of how he should do it, is useless.

Answer (score 2):

Are you working with Set Theory? If so, (remove*) solves the problem but it's not the procedure that describes set difference.

Set difference is A\B is defined by:
`A\B={x,such that x is in A and x is not in B}`

Therefore you need a procedure that tells you wheter an element is `in` a list or not. Then your `difference` code would look like:

```
(define difference
  (λ (A B)
    (remove* (list #f) (map 
     (λ (x) 
       (if (not (in x B))
         x
         #f
         )) A))))
```

In the above example I use remove*, and in my opinion it's not very elegant, so why not trying recursion? It's Racket in the end :).

```
(define difference2
  (λ (A B res)
    (cond 
      ((empty? A) (reverse res))
      ((not (in (car A) B)) (difference2 (cdr A) B (cons (car A) res)))
      (else (difference2 (cdr A) B res))
      )))
```

Note how in `difference2` i made no use of maps or removes.

The `reverse` function is used just in case you want the result to be ordered.

Analyze both examples, try to understand what I'm doing and post your results.

Let us know of any doubt!

**EDIT:**
Oh and about the other problem of assigning values of an operation to another variable (C++ like), you can do it very much like in C++. :p

Example

```
(define C (sum A B))
```

or

```
(define foo (+ (* pi x) (* 6 sigma)))
```

Comment: in the second example that you gave me,
 ((not (in (car A) B)) (difference2 (cdr A) B (cons (car A) res)))  <-- here, next to not, the "in" does not work. it says "unbound identifier in module in: in" ... any idea? thanks!

Comment: Yes it's unbound because I want you to code it. Think about it like you're searching for an specific toy in a box, you pick up the FIRST thing you grab and CHECK if it's the one you're looking for, if it is not, throw it and continue with the REST (check [link](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Lists__Iteration__and_Recursion.html?q=lists)) of the toys in the box until you finish. Let us know any doubt!

Also try to code it using recursion just as in the second example of code I gave you.